# Who thought applying real value definite integral to contour integral firstly？

Tags: math-history

Who thought applying real value definite integral to contour integral firstly？
Example
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{(x)}}{x} dx
$$
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \log{(\sin{(x)})} dx
$$

Comment: I think the systematic approach was due to Cauchy. But Euler allready had used complex analysis to solve a wide range of these problems.

Comment: Do you know the evidence that they use contour integral? If possible, please show me some article on the web.

Comment: As far as i know Euler never used contour integrals. But he used properties of complex number to solve Integrals.

Comment: As far as i know Euler never used contour integrals. But he used properties of complex number to solve Integrals. In his famous works on complex analysis he proved this Integral $$\frac{\Gamma (s)}{n|p|^s}\cos{(\alpha s)}=\int_0^{\infty}u^{ns-1}\exp{(-Re(p)u^n)}\cos{(Im(p)u^n)}du$$ (Zur Theorie komplexer Funktionen, 1768-1783; here is a video that is showing a non-rigorous proof based on Eulers proof https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VF7ud3Al6d8&list=PL3E4136E122545FBE&index=7)